# Ionic unable to change active segment button color

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, properties, version-control, segment

I have a small problem with my Ionic 5 and Angular application. 
So here it is, I have an ionic segment but it is impossible for me to change the background colour of the segment button that is active/checked. 
In addition to the official documentation, I tried many different methods read on forums but it remains impossible. 
Can you help me?

ion-segment in my home.html :

```
<ion-segment value='favorites' [(ngModel)]="segmentModel" (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" color="maindark" mode='ios' swipeGesture='true' scrollable='true'>
    <ion-segment-button value="favorites">
      <ion-label>Favoris</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="settings">
      <ion-label>Paramètres</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

SCSS of the segment in home.scss :

```
ion-segment {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  margin: 5vh 15vw 0 15vw;
  background-color: #2d303aab;
}

ion-segment-button {
  padding: 7px 0 7px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.segment-button-checked {
  color: #F8CF80 !important; // it works properly 

  // Tried all of that but nothing work
  background-color: #2D303A !important; 
  background: #2D303A !important; 
  --background: #2D303A !important; 
  --background-color: #2D303A !important; 
  --background-checked: #2D303A !important; 
}
```

the result : 
[image: The result]

Comment: You want to color the button? Sorry, I'm a bit confused on what is actually needed. Can you make a stackblitz so we can see the code for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The challenge you are experiencing has to do with the shadow DOM.](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/)

You could pierce the shadow DOM with something like:

```
::part(indicator-background) {
  background-color: #2D303A;
}
```

though that might be a little to global.

possibly [ng-deep](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) may work and be more targeted.

```
.segment-button-checked ::ng-deep{
  background-color: #2D303A;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. The first way worked prefectly for me:

.segment-button-checked::part(indicator-background) {
  background-color: #2D303A;
}

But unfortunately, the second way didn't worked for me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like you solved the problem elegantly by add the class target at the front. I learned something new as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using the host context:

```
:host {
  // Update the background color of the segment buttons
  ::part(indicator-background) {
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
  }
  
  // Update the text color of the selected segment button
  ion-segment ion-segment-button.segment-button-checked {
    color: var(--ion-color-light);
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following css code in styles working fine for me in ionic 6

```
    ion-segment {
background-color: rgb(3, 3, 63);

  ion-segment-button {
    color: rgb(119, 119, 115);
        }

  .segment-button-checked {
    color: #F8CF80 !important; // it works properly 
    
    background-color: #023b21de !important; 
  
  }

}
```